# Replace words VBA excel - Microsoft word

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for a word and replace it with nothing:

```
objWord.Documents.Open (C:\word.docx)


With objWord.ActiveDocument
Set myrange = .Content
With myrange.Find
    .Execute FindText:=txt1, ReplaceWith:=""
    .Execute FindText:=txt2, ReplaceWith:=""
    .Execute FindText:=txt3, ReplaceWith:=""
End With
End With
```

Problem with this is it searches for txt1 first, and if it doesn't find that it searches for txt2 and txt 3 BELOW the txt1 text. I want it to search the WHOLE document for txt1/2/3. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is flagged as Excel which I'm familiar with, it's Word but I'm thinking resetting myrange between each may work:

```
    With objWord.ActiveDocument
    Set myrange = .Content
    With myrange.Find
        .Execute FindText:=txt1, ReplaceWith:=""
    End With
    Set myrange = .Content
    With myrange.Find
        .Execute FindText:=txt2, ReplaceWith:=""
    End With
    Set myrange = .Content
    With myrange.Find
        .Execute FindText:=txt3, ReplaceWith:=""
    End With
    End With
```